# How to play minecraft against my son with 2 PCs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to play Minecraft against my son with us each on a different PC where we can create our own worlds without any other interference from other users.

Is that possible, what do we need (I assume 2x PC minecraft accounts) and how do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: It's similar to another question  'How can I host my own Minecraft server?' but since I didn't know what a 'minecraft server' is I never have found that question  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If both PC's are on the same LAN (in the same house, using the same router), you can simply load a game on one PC, press Escape, then click the **Open to LAN** button.  The 'Allow cheats' option will enable/disable commands, and you can set the default game mode. When ready click the **Start LAN World** button.

On the second PC, you can now go to 'Multiplayer' from the main menu, and you should be able to see the game running on the first PC - simply connect to it like you would any other server.

If you can't see it, then you may need to adjust Firewall settings on the 'host' PC.

Comment: Thanks, that looks to be the answer. I voted it as the answer but don't have enough reputation for it to count 

Comment: On the second PC it couldn't spot the first PC/server on the LAN.  I tried telling the firewall to let java through but still no joy.  So instead I had to connect directly via IP:port.  For completeness IP address comes from ipconfig (it will be something like 192.168.1.xxx) then colon (:) then the port (which minecraft tells you once the games reappears after clicking Open to LAN (normally a 5 digit number)